# Matlab plotting with lines of my X Y dataset

Tags: matlab, graphics, graph, matlab-figure

For example I have an x values and y values like this :

```
x = [0.5 , 1.5 , 2.5];
y = [3, 6, 9];
```

And I want to draw a graph like below. (Red lines and spesific red values on axis are important for me, scale of axis doesnt matter)
[image]

I am searching for a while but no luck. How can i do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Note that `x` and `y` are assumed to be *row* vectors.

```
stem(x,y,'r');                             %// plot vertical lines with circles
hold on                                    %// keep current graph; more will be added
plot([zeros(1,numel(x)); x], [y; y], 'r')  %// plot horizontal lines
set(gca, 'xtick',sort(x), 'ytick',sort(y)) %// set ticks on x and y axes
axis([0 6 0 10])                           %// set axis size
```

[image]

Comment: But there are no values on x and y axies ? I want them appear

Comment: Are you ok if _only those_ values appear, replacing the default 1, 2, 3, etc?

Comment: You could also use `set(gca,'XTick',sort(unique([get(gca,'XTick'),x])));` to add the new values without replacing the old ones.

Comment: I have an issue, Actually my data set is not monotonically increased. I gave here a simple data set. When i use your code, I gave an error : "Values must be monotonically increasing" and result graphic is not like yours. What can i do for not monotonically increasing data sets ?

Comment: @SedatKURT That's because the `set` line requires monotone increasing values. See edit: `set(gca, 'xtick',sort(x), 'ytick',sort(y))`

Answer (score 0):

The code below will pull the automatic x-axis and y-axis labels and add in any additional unique (not already included) axis labels for the lines that you've specified.  IT will also plot any arbitrarily large data set provided.

```
clc; clear; clf; % // preamble to clear previous data and plots

x = [0.23 , 1.5 , 2.5];
y = [3, 4.5, 9]; 

hold on
    for i=1:numel(x)
        plot([x(i),x(i)],[0,y(i)],'-r');  % // plots vertical lines
        plot([0,x(i)],[y(i),y(i)],'-r');  % // plots horizontal lines
    end
    scatter(x,y,70,'r','MarkerEdgeColor','r','MarkerFaceColor','w')
hold off

axis([0 max(x)+1 0 max(y)+1]); % // changes axis to be [0 1+max(x)] and [0 1+max(y)]

XTickAutomatic=get(gca,'XTick'); % // retrieves current x-axis tick marks    
YTickAutomatic=get(gca,'YTick'); % // retrieves current y-axis tick marks       

set(gca,'XTick',sort(unique([XTickAutomatic,x]))) % // create new ticks marks with any unique x-coordinates
set(gca,'YTick',sort(unique([YTickAutomatic,y]))) % // create new ticks marks with any unique y-coordinates
```